# Is there something like the JQuery PHP Library, using $.ajax instead of $.php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

The [JQuery PHP Library](http://jquery.hohli.com/) creates an object `$.php` which works similarly to `$.ajax`. like this:

```
$.php(url);
php.complete = function (){
    $('#loading').slideUp('slow');
}
```

... by doing so it adds a whole bunch of functionality which lets you do jQuery-y stuff from the server. But I don't like how the complete function works. I'd prefer this:

```
$.ajax(url)
   .complete(function() {
      $('#loading').slideUp('slow');
   });
```

... The difference is that I want to have a custom **complete** handler for each separate call. The way it is now, if I use jQuery PHP and do a second `$.php` call and define a `php.complete` handler, the new `php.complete` handler will overwrite the first.

Does a solution like this already exist? If not, how would one go about [modifying the jQuery PHP library](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-php/source/browse/trunk/javascript/jquery.php.js) to make it function this way?

NOTE: In jQuery 1.8+ complete() is deprecated in favor of always()

Comment: On line 19 of http://code.google.com/p/jquery-php/source/browse/trunk/javascript/jquery.php.js change `$.ajax` to `return $.ajax`

Comment: You mean change the php function, like this?
`$.extend({
    php: function (url, params) {
        $.ajax({
           ....
        });
      return $.ajax;
    }
});`

Comment: Yes, and No. Only change line 19 at the link i provided. Here's a pastebin to demonstrate the change: http://pastebin.com/tCzMBGtD

Comment: Thank you! This works nicely. If you want to add the solution below I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify line 19 to return the jqXHR object from the method.

http://pastebin.com/tCzMBGtD

```
$.ajax(...
```

becomes

```
return $.ajax(...
```